# In libgdx how do you attach a circleshape on top of a rectangle?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have created a body and I have created two separate fixtures, one fixture creates a rectangle shape and the other fixture creates a circle shape. But when I use the .createfixture it puts the circle in the centre of the rectangle, I want the circle on top of the rectangle like a matchstick.

here is my code don't know what to do ...

```
rectangleBodyDef = new BodyDef();
rectangleBodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
rectangleBodyDef.position.set(10,20);
rectangleBody = world.createBody(rectangleBodyDef);
rectangleBodyShape = new PolygonShape();
rectangleBodyShape.setAsBox(2f, 0.75f);
rectangleBodyFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
rectangleBodyFixtureDef.shape = rectangleBodyShape;
rectangleBodyFixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;
rectangleBody.createFixture(rectangleBodyFixtureDef);


/**********************CREATING THE SECOND BODY (CIRCLE BODY) ************/


circleShape = new CircleShape();
circleShape.setRadius(0.75f);
circleFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
circleFixtureDef.shape = circleShape;
circleFixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;
rectangleBody.createFixture(circleFixtureDef);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fixture Definitions](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/FixtureDef.html) are relative to the body position, set the [CircleShape](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/CircleShape.html) position to be a little above the rectangle one:

```
CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
circleShape.setRadius(0.75f);

circleShape.setPosition(new Vector2(0,2));   //<------Add this

FixtureDef circleFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
circleFixtureDef.shape = circleShape;
circleFixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;
rectangleBody.createFixture(circleFixtureDef);
```

Answer (score 0):

The location of the circleFixtureDef is relative to the location of your rectangleBody. Set the location of circleFixtureDef to something other than 0,0.

Comment: how do you set the location of this with a fixtureDef is it possible ?Could you show me a line of code please that does this

Comment: I recommend googling something like "Box2D create fixture" and making an attempt.

Comment: I have googled everywhere which is why I am asking on the forums and i have made an attempt as shown in the code above you said you could set position with the fixturedef but is it possible because I have tried and it just shows up as errors on eclipse.

Comment: Then post the updated code along with the full text of any errors you're seeing.