# LibGDX + Box2D | How to make a joint between 2 bodies stiff? / How to make objects fall faster?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I use LibGDX as well as Box2D for my platformer.
I got a prototype working before but I had problems with slopes, because I just applya force to the center of the player to the left or the right. So I thought why not let Box2D do the work, since I am already using it. I tried to implement this:

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2017 (this video shows the idea pretty good)

The Basic idea is to make the player not just out of a box. But instead use a circle shape for the feet. This way slopes shouldn't be such a pain the make. So I created 2 bodies. Joint them to test it and I found something odd. Both bodies together took way more impuls to let the player body jump than it took a box with the same width, height.

Example for equal jumping of the box and the player:

```
if (GameKeys.isPressed(GameKeys.SPACE)) {
    if (cl.isPlayerOnGround()) {
            playerBody.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 1800), playerBody.getWorldCenter(), true);playerBody.getWorldCenter(), true);
            box.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 10), playerBody.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
}
```

The reason for that is that I applied a high desity to the player body to prevent the joint from bouncing and make it more stiff.
My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to prevent the joint between the feets and the body of the player to be very bouncy than to just set it's density very high?
2. Is there any commonly used formula to get a good density, or is it just tweaking the values until it feels right?
3. Is there a way to let an object fall faster besides messing with the fall constant (-9.81f)? The player object and the box feel a bit to floaty at the moment.

I know these are multiple questions and I hope I don't ask for too much, but thanks to anyone who even reads all this mess ^^

The Pixels per Meter (PPM) is 32!

My Play.java:
http://pastebin.com/HB9h6MV6

P.s.: Sry for my bad english. I'm not a native English speaker (German). :)

Comment: Another example for making the player out of a circle and a box:


[EXAMPLE](https://github.com/piotr-j/LudumDare27/blob/master/LDG/src/com/pj/ld/game/Player.java)

Comment: I am not verry experienced with `Box2D` but for number 3: Use `setGravityScale` to give the object a higher gravity.

Comment: You don't need two bodies. Just put two fixtures onto one body.

Comment: @iforce2d

I already tried that. But how do I set the position of the second fixture (the circle) relativ to the center of the box? Because at the moment it just get's added to the center of the box.
Code:http://pastebin.com/576MVTV3

Comment: CircleShape should have a 'center' member (b2Vec2) you can set.

Comment: Try "setPosition" as in the docs: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/CircleShape.html See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139801/in-libgdx-how-do-you-attach-a-circleshape-on-top-of-a-rectangle

Comment: @iforce2d

THX! That's exactly what I was searching for :O
I already looked in the API but it looks like I overlooked it. 
Btw. your tutorials are awesome! At the moment I work on the jumping and movement of the player and your totorials are very helpfull!